# ddply for entire data with no groups?

Tags: r, plyr

Is it possible to use ddply to summarize the data without stratifying by a group? I've tried something like

```
ddply(df, summarize, a = sum(a, na.rm=T), b = sum(b, na.rm=T))
```

Comment: Have you just tried rowSums or colSums? What are you trying to sum?

Comment: Don't use `ddply`, just use `summarize` directly.

Comment: I will try with summarize. I wanted to do broad sweeping sums and means by various variables into on df like with ddply, which is why rowSums/colSums is not an option.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function `ddply` will accept an "empty" grouping variable and perform the analysis on the entire table.

With subgroups:

```
ddply(baseball, .(lg), c("nrow", "ncol"))
  lg  nrow ncol
1       65   22
2 AA   171   22
3 AL 10007   22
4 FL    37   22
5 NL 11378   22
6 PL    32   22
7 UA     9   22
```

Without subgroups:

```
ddply(baseball, .(), c("nrow", "ncol"))
   .id  nrow ncol
1 <NA> 21699   22
```

Comment: Thanks, Andrie! I had deleted the .() not knowing you could keep them. This is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Andrie! I need to use function `ldply()`, and get the names of the list elements into the `.id` variable, but `.()` returns a missing value whereas a nonempty argument e.g. `.(sex)` returns the name as needed. I don't know if the missing value in `.id` is a bug. I made a workaround, but it is not very convenient:

```
Reduce(rbind.fill,
       lapply(list(.(), .(sex)),
              function(x) {
                res <- ldply(d, function(y) ddply(y, x, summarize, otos=sum(sample.n), lab=sum(obs.n)))
                if (all(is.na(res$.id)))
                  res$.id <- names(d)
                res
              }))
```